# Entry for Grub1 on sda3 into the main Grub2 on sda

Tags: boot, grub2

I have ubuntu 10.10 on sda1. Archlinux with its bootloader, Grub1, on sda3. Ubuntu's bootloader grub2 in on sda. How can I create an entry for sda3 Grub1 in ubuntu's sda Grub2. Simply put, On bootup I should see Grub2 first and it should have an entry for Grub1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put

```
# (1) Arch Linux
 echo "Adding Arch Linux" >&2
 cat << EOF
 menuentry "Arch Linux" {
 set root=(hd0,2)
 chainloader +1
}
```

in /etc/grub.d/40_custom and then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reference: http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Configuration%20File%20Commands.html#chainloader_boot_entry

Answer (score 1):

GRUB2 supports the chainloader command ( that instead of booting directly a kernel, simply 'pass the stick' to the next boot loader ).

So in your /boot/grub.cfg file you should add something that resemble this:

```
# (1) Arch Linux
 menuentry "Arch Linux" {
 set root=(hd0,2)
 chainloader +1
}
```

**Be aware that if you update your grub2 configuration by its tool ( update-grub ) you will need to apply this setting again.**